# php can not parse json data to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, cakephp

The question is very common in stackoverflow. I have been to too many solution provided in this forum for problem like mine. but it did not help. So i am posting it. Please please be kind enough to answer me.

Problem:
I am trying to send an integer from cakephp controller function to view having ajax call.
I keep getting this error for all the solutions i tried from here and other forums.

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0"

Please tell me what is wrong looking at my code :
I can see clearly i get data in json format in php while i make echo but not in main Ajax call.

```
Console says :the result is {"data":1}
```

Controller :

```
public function addit()
    {
        $mycount      = 1;
        $responseJSON = array(
            'data' => $mycount
        );
        //$responseJSON = array('status' =>'true', 'result'=>$arr);
        header('content-type:application/json');
        $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
        echo $response;
    }
```

**ajaxcall in view:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bn_cart').click(function(event){
          //alert('clicked');
          var form_data = $(this).serialize();

          var id = $('#id').val();
          alert("your item id is "+ id);
          var csrfToken = <?php echo(json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken'))) ?>;
               //alert("your form data "+csrfToken);
              event.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
                    },
                  url:'../addit',
                  type:'POST',

                  data: { id : id },
                  dataType:'json',

              success:function(xhr, response){
                    var respons = response;
                    console.log("conosle success says "+ (respons.result));
                    alert("success"+respons.result);

                },
              error:function(xhr, e,etype,response){
                    //alert("<br>error<br>"+ error.responseText.message);
                    alert("response = "+ response +"xhr = "+ xhr + "  e = " + e + "  etype = "+ etype);
                    console.log(" response =" + response + "error ="+ e +"xhr = "+ xhr + "  etype = "+ etype );
                    //  $("#result").html(error.Message);
                    // alert('error ='+(error.Message));
                  }
          });

        });
    });


Network>Header:
Request URL: http://localhost/shoppingCart/products/addit
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 583
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 23 Oct 2018 14:10:08 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.1.15
X-DEBUGKIT-ID: 182187f0-546d-48d4-9e5a-6746a40dba64
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.15
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: csrfToken=0a8a1f6e98fe8274e80f9bdcb3ba5df66a5af4296126302d3e79bf44e856ed720438947bb93f041f772ac1e39d083aa2d88c5159697c9843a8b04eace893260b; CAKEPHP=mhphclr8cuvacrlotbit45dd3l; csrftoken=t0p47S5P7NBcwGGQ9sfuNGLi5JJDkll8ifuCWhG3W6MRSIewe9GtRNjanPUqms54
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost
Referer: http://localhost/shoppingCart/products/view/2
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token: 0a8a1f6e98fe8274e80f9bdcb3ba5df66a5af4296126302d3e79bf44e856ed720438947bb93f041f772ac1e39d083aa2d88c5159697c9843a8b04eace893260b
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest


Network>>Response : 
{"data":1}
```

Comment: `echo "<br>the result is ". $response;` will be making the response non-valid JSON, because it's not valid JSON. Just echo `$response`.

Comment: remove '<br>' from your echo

Comment: @JonStirling ..Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it didnt help yet ..same error : response = undefined xhr = [object Object]  e = parsererror  etype = SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Thanks for response ...but it could not help me yet

Comment: @vins try adding `encode:true` on your ajax setup and hardrefresh the page

Comment: FYI, your `error` callback function arguments are incorrect.  It only takes three arguments, not four.  You might want to double-check the details of [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect the changes that you made after Jon's suggestion?  And also include the response that is shown in your browser's Network tab (not console output that you are generating, the actual raw response).

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks but it does not yet solve my problem. :(

Comment: _What_ doesn't solve your problem? You keep saying that nothing's working, but you haven't actually shown that you're making any changes.

Comment: @PatrickQ Updated!

Comment: @PatrickQ anything more ???

Comment: What if you put `exit;` after `echo $response;`?  And do you have this publicly accessible somewhere?

Comment: @PatrickQ no my friend its not public but if you want we can talk and i can show all (dont know how). BTW exit; does not seem to have any effect or at least i didnt notice any.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return your response encoded in json. You are trying to echo a non json-encoded response which will not work.

```
public function addit()
{
    $mycount      = 1;
    $responseJSON = array(
        'data' => $mycount
    );
    //$responseJSON = array('status' =>'true', 'result'=>$arr);
    header('content-type:application/json');
    return json_encode($responseJSON);
}
```

Ajax call :

```
success:function(data, status, jqxhr)
            var respons = data;
            console.log("conosle success says "+ (respons.result));
            alert("success"+respons.result);

        },
```

Comment: You need to explain to OP what you did that he ddnt do

Comment: @Bernard Pagoaga thanks for your response. I have tried it many times it gives different error : response = undefinedxhr = [object Object]  e = error  etype = Internal Server Error (i can yet see data in console)

Comment: Also the success callback takes the data as first parameter, not the xhr object : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.